# How to insert a column with the dropdown value which came from database

Tags: php

I have a page where the orders are assigned to employees for this I have a dropdown which gets the employee names from database,

this Is the code:

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'pms');

$sql = "SELECT emp_first_name, emp_id FROM employee";
$result = $db->query($sql);
echo "<select name='emp_id'>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['emp_id'] ."'>" . $row['emp_first_name']. "(" . $row['emp_id']. ")</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

$db->close();
?>
```

in this code how do I get the employee id and insert it into the assigned to column in the database

this is the command for updating table:

```
if (isset($_POST['assign'])){
  if (isset($_POST['checkbox'])){
      $update = "update orders set assign_to = "$emp_id";
      if($update){
         echo(passed);
      }
  else{
     echo "failed";
  }
}
```

pls fill the remaining query I am new to php

Comment: You must provide more information. You already have the employee id in your update query? You must know what order id update since `update orders set assign_to = "$emp_id` will update any orders and assign them to the same id. also provide the full code, what's `assign` and `checkbox`?

Comment: @ALFA `assign` is the button click name and checkbox is the checkbox id, I am trying to use stored procedure pls help

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to get the value of your droplist ffrom POST by using the droplist name

Do this
(isset($_POST['assign'])){
  if (isset($_POST['checkbox'])){
$emp_id=$_POST['droplistname'];
      $update = "update orders set assign_to = ?";
$stmt=$db->prepare($update);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $emp_id);
      if($stmt->execute()){
         echo "passed";
      }
  else{
echo $db->error;
     echo "failed";
  }
}
```

Comment: can i know what is ? refer to

Comment: and also can I use stored procedure for doing this. if possible explain me how pls

Comment: Its *blind* parameter. Then you bind that paremetrr with any variable so it will automatically use the binded variable in the query.

Comment: can't get you pls explain

Comment: The main purpose is to make the DBMS differentiate between query and data. So you replace the data with **?** Then you later bind the data to it or them. This is to prevent SQL injection, because in SQL injection, it happens when  data is been treated as command or query. Because some words and characters are considered by the DBMS as command, so if you have a data which is or are such characters or words, it's possible the DBMS will execute it, so an attacker will take advantage and write malicious queries as data and it will be executed in the course of running the legitimate query.